# Installing npm package to different location

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have a project structure like this:

```
parent/
    package.json
    node_modules/
    child/
        package.json
```

**I want to install the packages in `parent/node_modules` directory from `child` directory location.**

Whenever i run `npm install jquery --save` from `child` directory i want  it to install the `jquery` package in `parent/node_modules` and to save dependencies in `child/package.json` file.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do `npm install jquery --prefix ../` to install it to the parents `node_modules`. However, if you use this with `--save`, it will save it to the parents `package.json`.

I would just do `npm install jquery --save && mv ./node_modules/jquery ../node_modules`